# template matching with a web camera using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

take a look at the following code.

```
import cv
import cv2

print "starting now"
im = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
template=cv.LoadImage("/home/patrick/Desktop/card.JPG")


W=3648
H=2736

w,h = cv.GetSize(template)

width = W - w + 1

height = H - h + 1

result = cv.CreateImage((width, height), 32, 1)
#image= cv.CreateImage((width, height), 32, 1)
cv.MatchTemplate(im, template, result, cv.CV_TM_CCORR)

(min_x, max_y, minloc, maxloc) = cv.MinMaxLoc(result)

(x, y) = minloc

print (x,y)
```

when I run I get eh following error message

```
    cv.MatchTemplate(im, template, result, cv.CV_TM_CCORR)
TypeError: CvArr argument 'image' must be IplImage, CvMat or CvMatND. Use fromarray() to convert numpy arrays to CvMat or cvMatND
```

How do I convert images from a web cam into data that can processed using match template?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your im variable is a videoCapture object. You need to [grab](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvcapturefromcam#videocapture-grab) a frame to get the image.

The other problem is that you're using the old cv interface. The newer cv2 is much nicer to work with. [Here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)'s the template matching tutorial.

Comment: new problem, I used tutorial in the link above to rebuild my code, inserting my video capture code in place of the image to be analyzed but now I got this new error  <unknown> is not a numpy array for both the copy and the match template function.

Comment: make sure, that you pass the correct path to imread, ty displaying the image after it's been loaded.

Comment: maybe I was not clear in that last post, I was using images taken directly from a webcamera. Loading the images is not the problem. The problem is that need to covert the tuples produce by the camera and turn them into something matchtemplate can process